# How to pass multiple values to Bootstrap pop-up from anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am displaying some fields in a table with labels and also an anchor tag to edit the data.

When the user clicks the Edit Link, the pop is shown with Current Value and also have a textbox to Update the Value with new one.

I want to pass the current value of Lable to the pop-up and also the column name which will be hidden from the user by which I can easily get the column name which have to be updated.

I want to pass column name because there many fields in this page but I have developed only one pop-up for all, so the data which will shown in pop-up will be dynamic as it depends upon the anchor which was clicked.

This is My Modal-PopUp Code :

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              Current Value :
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="Curr_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              New Value :
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="New_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here I am calling the Modal Pop-up :

```
     <th style="width:15%;">First Name :</th>
 <td style="width:18%;">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_fname"></asp:Label>
<span> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">                                                                 <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                                           </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
 </span>
 </td>
```

I've gone through many links but couldn't fine the solution for passing multiple values.

Can any any one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried the following code using javascript but it still not working :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".edit").click(function () {

                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var tdRecords = $(tr).children();
                var firstName = $(tdRecords[0]).text();
                var lastName = $(tdRecords[1]).text();

                $("#Curr_Val").val(firstName);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var $ = jQuery;
     $(document).ready(function () {
     var selectedTab = $("#<%=hfTab.ClientID%>");
     var tabId = selectedTab.val() != "" ? selectedTab.val() : "personal";
     $('#dvTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
     $("#dvTab a").click(function () {
     selectedTab.val($(this).attr("href").substring(1));
     });
       });
  </script> 

  <style>
  body {
  text-align:left;
  color:#000000;
    }
  </style>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
  <!-- Top content -->
   <div class="top-content"> 

     <div class="inner-bg">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:-50px;">                   
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 myprofilediv" style="vertical-align:central;">                    
                   <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding:10px;">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                           <a class="btn btn-link-1" href="MyProfile.aspx?do=edit" style="font-weight:bold; float:right;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Edit My Profile</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    <h1 class="wow fadeInLeftBig profilehead">My Profile</h1><br />
                                <div id="dvTab">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                        <li><a href="#personal" aria-controls="personal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#fund" aria-controls="pf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fund Nominee</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#edu" aria-controls="edu" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Education Details</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#fam" aria-controls="fam" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Family Details</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#emphist" aria-controls="emphist" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employment History</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div id="personal" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">

                                            <table style="height:15%;" class="table">
                                                   <tr>
                                                       <td style="width:60%;"> <br />   <h3 style="text-align:center;">Personal Information</h3> </td>
                                                       <td style="width:12%;"><br /><asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="ImgHandler.ashx?typ=profile&emp=46" /></td>
                                                   </tr>
                                               </table>
                                            <br />
                                            <table class="table-responsive table table-bordered mytable">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="width:15%;">First Name :</th>
                                                <td style="width:18%;">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_fname"></asp:Label>

                                                        <%-- <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">--%>
                                                       <a class="edit" href="#">
                                                             <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                         </a>
                                                       &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                       <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>


                                                </td>
                                                <th style="width:13%;">Middle Name :</th>
                                                <td style="width:20%;">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_mname"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <th style="width:18%;">Last Name :</th>
                                                <td style="width:20%;">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_lname"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the way you call your modal popup, you should ideally be calling it from javascript.

Before calling the modal you will need to find the table row(or any other record you need to update) relative to the position of the clicked link and populate the **current value** text box with this data.Once you've done all this you can call `$('#myModal').modal('show');` to show the modal.

Here's a complete example.Pasted it as is in a new web page, understand how it works and finally apply to your solution:

**HTML:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".edit").click(function () {

                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var tdRecords = $(tr).children();
                var firstName = $(tdRecords[0]).text();
                var lastName = $(tdRecords[1]).text();

                $("#Curr_Val").val(firstName);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                Current Value :
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="Curr_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                New Value :
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="New_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Denis</td>
                <td>Wessels</td>
                <td><a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bob</td>
                <td>The Builder</td>
                <td><a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".edit").click(function () {

                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var tdRecords = $(tr).children();
                var middleName = $(tdRecords[3]).children(0).html();
                var lastName = $(tdRecords[5]).children(0).html();

                $("#Curr_Val").val(middleName);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                Current Value :
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="Curr_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                New Value :
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="New_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table-responsive table table-bordered mytable">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 15%;">First Name :</th>
                <td style="width: 18%;">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_fname"></asp:Label>
                    <a class="edit" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true">Edit</i>
                    </a>
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
                <th style="width: 13%;">Middle Name :</th>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_mname" Text="My Middle Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <th style="width: 18%;">Last Name :</th>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_lname" Text="My Last Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Do exactly what I suggested.Create a new, clean web page.Then take all my code copy->paste->run in visual studio

Comment: Denis your code is getting the data from td text but my data is printing in labels... How can i resolve this

Comment: Add debugger; to your javascript code and use Ctrl+Shift+J in Google Chrome to debug your javascript and see exactly where it's breaking in YOUR code.Then make the necessary adjustments to get it working.I already gave you sample code that works and explained to you how to make changes to your code to get it working on your side.Please put in some effort to figure the problem out.

Comment: Yes Denis your code is working fine when the text is placed in td except label.

Comment: So then change the code to find the label.If you don't know how to do that use Google and do a little trial and error

Comment: Denis I've gone through google but didn't find any working solution.I think there is a problem in rendering my Js. Can you please help me as I am not good in Js

Comment: I've also tried debugger but it's not breaking any where

Comment: Copy updated code as is,no extras, just copy -> paste -> and run in Visual Studio

Comment: Yes Denis Still same problem.Nothing is happening.

Comment: But this code is also working if it is in separate file :(

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rodoveyugo/edit?html,js,output Here I've Pasted the entire page code.You can Check it pleasee :(